# Order or Orderby in tax_query (How to define order of terms in WP_Query)

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I am trying to work out how I can define the order of terms in my WP_QUERY.

I am creating a knowledge base. I have a CPT called knowledge-base and a taxonomy called topics.

My code outputs all of the topic terms and then loops through 4 posts that have the meta key top_four_num, this is to show the top four questions in the topic. Then I have a nested loop that the rest of the posts in that topic. These are hidden by JQUERY, the user clicks a 'show all link' to reveal.

Everything is working as I want it to, but I cannot work out how to change to order of the terms. Currently, they appear in Alphabetical order.

I have checked to codex and tax_query has no order based parameters. Can anyone point me in the right direction to being able to control tax_query order?

My code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
        <?php

    /**
     * Knowledge Base        
     */

    //Call in the header
    get_header();

    //* Customize search form input box text
    add_filter( 'genesis_search_text', 'sp_search_text' );
    function sp_search_text( $text ) {
        return esc_attr( 'Ask us a question...' );
    }

    // Remove div.site-inner's div.wrap
    add_filter( 'genesis_structural_wrap-site-inner', '__return_empty_string' );

    //* Add custom body class to the head
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'sp_body_class' );
    function sp_body_class( $classes ) {

            $classes[] = 'KB';
            return $classes;
    } ?>

    <style>.site-inner {
        max-width: none!important;
        padding-top: 0;
    } </style>


    <!-- Top Banner -->
    <div style = "text-align: center; " class = "top-banner">
    <h1 style = "color: white;">Knowledge base showcase</h1>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
        <!--body class-->
    <div class = "body-kb">

    <?php
    // Begin Main Topic loop
    $_terms = get_terms( array('topic') );

    foreach ($_terms as $term) :
    $ids = get_field('top_four', false, false);
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $_first = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'         => 'knowledge-base', 
                    'order'      => 'ASC',               
                    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num', 
                    'meta_key'          => 'top_four_num',               
                    'posts_per_page'    => -4,                
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'topic',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term_slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                ));

        if( $_first->have_posts() ) :
            ?> <div class = "container1"><?php
     //Output Term name
            echo '<div class = "term-name"><h2>'. $term->name .'</h2></div>';
            echo '<hr id="short-line" align="left" width="100">';

            while ( $_first->have_posts() ) : $_first->the_post();
            ?>

     <?php 
             //Loop counter to add divs to first loop returned posts 
             if( 0 == $_first->current_post ) {
            ?> <div class = "example-left"> <?php
        }?>
     <?php  if( 2 == $_first->current_post ) {
    ?> </div> <?php
        }?>
       <?php  if( 2 == $_first->current_post ) {
            ?> <div class = "example-right"> <?php
        }?>         
             <?php // output the post infomation ?>
                <div class="answers">
                    <h4><a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <p><?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url', true ); ?></p>
                </div>    


            <?php
            endwhile;?>


    <?php // Begin Secondary Hidden Content loop ?>
               <?php $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $_second = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'         => 'knowledge-base',
                    'order'             => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page'    => 10, //important for a PHP memory limit warning
                   /* 'offset'            => 5*/
                    'meta_key'          => 'priority',       
                    'meta_value'        => '1',  
                    'meta_compare'      => '>=',                 
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'topic',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term_slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                )); 

                if( $_second->have_posts() ) :
            ?>
    </div>
            <!---JQUERY HIDE SWITCH BUTTONS--> 
    <div class = "view-more"><a class="arrow-link" data-expand="howitworks-expand">View more<img class="main-arrow" src="/wp-content/uploads/arrow@2x-1.png"></a></div>
    <div class = "show-content"><?php       
          $i = 0;
            while ( $_second->have_posts() ) : $_second->the_post();
            ?>


        <?php //Output hidden loop into two columns automatically
        if ($i == 0) echo '<div class="one-half first">';
      if ($i == (round($_second->post_count / 2))) echo '</div><div class="one-half">';   


       ?> <p class = "rest-of-p sub"><a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                    <p><?php get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'url', true ); ?></p><?php


      if ($i == round($_second->post_count)) echo '</div>';
      $i++; 

    ?>        
          <?php endwhile;?>
     <?PHP wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
             </div>
                    <?php endif;?>

                   <?PHP //LOOP 2 END ?>
    <!--stop container-->
    </div>
    </div><?php       

        endif;
    endforeach;

    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
     // Call in footer 
    get_footer();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`get_terms` documentation:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

> `orderby (string)`: Field(s) to order terms by. Accepts term fields ('name', 'slug', 'term_group', 'term_id', 'id', 'description'), 'count' for term taxonomy count, 'include' to match the 'order' of the $include param, 'meta_value', 'meta_value_num', the value of $meta_key, the array keys of $meta_query, or 'none' to omit the ORDER BY clause. Defaults to 'name'.

Example:

```
get_terms([
     'taxonomy' => 'topic',
     'orderby'  => 'field',
     'order'    => 'ASC/DESC',    
]);
```

Comment: Great!! Works perfectly, completely missed the get_terms array. Thanks again! :)